# I am Trying to run a titanium project in ios simulator but getting some node error

Tags: node.js, titanium-sdk

I am Trying to run a titanium project with appcelerator studio in simulator but getting some node error, I have used same node version from which it was developed, please help me out

Error below

File

```
"/Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 971, in WriteActions
    "Spaces in action output filenames not supported (%s)"  % output)
    "Spaces in action output filenames not supported (%s)"  % output)
AssertionError: Spaces in action output filenames not supported (/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/build/MobileDevice.framework)
AssertionError: Spaces in action output filenames not supported (/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/build/MobileDevice.framework)
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device
gyp gyp ERR!ERR!  Systemnode -v Darwin 19.0.0
 v13.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR!gyp  commandERR! "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node" "--module_name=node_ios_device" "--module_path=/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
 not ok 
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device
gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64/node_ios_device.node --module_name=node_ios_device --module_path=/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device/binding/node-v79-darwin-x64 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/czmac01/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/9.1.0.v20200422074103/node_modules/node-ios-device
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v13.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to the LTS version 12.16.x and try to re-install the node packages after you moved to node 12.16.x:

`npm install -g titanium appcelerator alloy`

Also keep in mind: `9.1.0.v20200422074103` is a nightly build, so not a supported version.

Another thing to look at:

Since there is this error `Spaces in action output filenames not supported` you could edit: 
`/Users/czmac01/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py` and add a log where it throws that error to see which file is making the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works !. But now like whenever the simulator start launching after successful building the simulator terminate suddenly, any idea ?